# Who is the "emperor of BL"?

Tags: fudanshi-koukou-seikatsu

In episode 4 of *Fudanshi Koukou Seikatsu*, there's a gag where Sakaguchi mentions "the emperor [or empress?] of BL, Mori███████yuki". Judging from the bleeping-out of the name, I assume this is a reference to a real person who draws BL manga. But who?

I had a look through [all the people on MAL whose family names begin with "Mori" and whose personal names end with "yuki"](https://myanimelist.net/people.php?q=mori%20yuki) and didn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely to be a reference to veteran male voice actor [Morikawa Toshiyuki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toshiyuki_Morikawa) ([森川智之](http://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E6%A3%AE%E5%B7%9D%E6%99%BA%E4%B9%8B)). He is known to have done dubbed voice-overs for many famous (and handsome) Hollywood actors,  as well as the [voices](https://myanimelist.net/people/6/Toshiyuki_Morikawa) of several well-known bishounen anime characters such as Griffith from *Berserk*,  Sephiroth from *FF7*, and Naraku from *Inuyasha*.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I incorrectly assumed that the person would be an artist, so I skipped over all the voice actors on MAL. Oops.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the name, the one dubbed as the Emperor of BL is Toshiyuki Morikawa. There is an [interview in MAL](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/interview/2009-08-27/interview-toshiyuki-morkiawa-voice-of-d.gray-man-tyki-mikk) that supports this.

> Q: We've got many, many female fans today. In addition to regular anime, you've been playing many roles for female-oriented drama CDs. What's the major difference between the two types of performance, and how did you feel when you first started voicing female-oriented drama CDs?
>
> A: I'm very happy to see so many female fans, but I also noticed a few guys among them. At first I worried for them, fearing that they might feel uncomfortable in the overwhelming female crowds, but I was relieved when I saw them enjoying the autograph session very much. **As for boys-love (BL) drama CD: you know that I've played many BL roles, and I love those titles very much, for their storytelling are often superior to those of regular anime, plus I wouldn't be able to play so many different roles without BL drama CDs.** The most memorable performance was with my good friend Shinichiro Miki in Embracing Love: Cherished Spring (Haru wo Daiteita), which had two actors as male protagonists, thus in addition to playing the character we had to deliver the message of the work as well.

As far as I know, he don't draw BL manga, but he do voice many of them as he said himself.